# Deserialize a varying number of objects into a list in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

My Spring Boot app makes a call to a REST API and receives a JSON with a varying number of entities. E.g.

```
{
  "content": {
    "guest_1": {
      "name": {
        "firstName": "a",
        "lastName": "b"
      },
      "vip": false
    },
    "guest_2": {
      "name": {
        "firstName": "c",
        "lastName": "d"
      },
      "vip": false
    },
    ...more guests omitted...
  }
}
```

There can be 1 to many guests and I don't know their number upfront. As you can see, they aren't in an array, they are objects instead.

I'd like to avoid deserializing into a class like

```
public class Content {

  @JsonProperty("guest_1")
  private Guest guest1;

  @JsonProperty("guest_2")
  private Guest guest2;

  // More Guests here each having their own field
}
```

What I'd like to use is

```
public class Content {

  private List<Guest> guests;
}
```

The `@JsonAnySetter` annotation I read about at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations looks promising but I couldn't get it to work.

*3.2. Convert to an object* at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model looks also good but it didn't work out either.

I'm not sure if I can make Jackson do this in a declarative way or I should write a custom `JsonDeserializer`. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonAnySetter` will work as it allows to specify a POJO type as second parameter. You could recreate the example JSON as, omitting `setXXX()` and `getXXX()` methods on POJOs for clarity:

```
private static class Content {
    private Guests content;
}

private static class Guests  {
    private List<Guest> guests = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void addGuest(String name, Guest value) {
        guests.add(value);
    }
}

private static class Guest {
    private Name name;
    private boolean vip;
}

private static class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

With your JSON example will produce:

```
Content root = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Content.class);
root.getContent().getGuests().stream()
        .map(Guest::getName)
        .map(Name::getFirstName)
        .forEach(System.out::println); // a, c
```

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm! Looks like I was close to the solution but missing something. Instead of a List, I ended up putting the values into a Map where the name parameter is the key. Thanks for your quick response!